# Django DRF adding a row with a query in the serializer return error

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Hi i got a problem with DRF im using this as serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from Sitios.models import Sitio, muestras


class SitiosSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    ultimo_estado = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Sitio
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
        datatables_always_serialize = ('id', 'SitioNombre', 'url')

def get_ultimo_estado(self, obj):
    f = muestras.objects.filter(sitio__id=obj.pk).latest('-muestraDate')
    return str(f.estado)
```

the problem is the query set i tested this in the console return the right value but when i put it into the function

```
muestras matching query does not exist.
```

this problem happens when there is a problem with the foreign key but it works in the console. i rely dont know what im doing wrong or if you can suggest another course of action.

Comment: can you post your queryset tested?

Comment: add console log too.

Comment: this the error log [http://dpaste.com/26EWRJG] and the queryset that works is the same but with the part of the obj.pk some thing like this `f = muestras.objects.filter(sitio__id=1).latest('-muestraDate')` where one is the primary key of one site.

Comment: and the log print in the console is `Sitios.models.muestras.DoesNotExist: muestras matching query does not exist.`